CSRF attacks problem on JSF and Primefaces
Recently, my web page has passed a pentest and the company that did it has found a problem with the CSRF attacks.
I am using:

Primefaces 10.0.0
Wildfly 23

I have read that Primefaces 10.0.0 has automatic XSS and XSRF prevention Primefaces documentation and JSF is protected too Cross Site Request Forgery prevention via 'Referer' header and CSRF, XSS and SQL Injection attack prevention in JSF.
I have looked for something that validates this in the back-end request, and effectively, there are request body parameters that make you think that is preventing those attacks.

primefaces.nonce
javax.faces.ViewState

The problem is when I change or delete the parameter primefaces.nonce, because the request works fine too. (I have done it with Burp Suite)
I have added this, to my web.xml file:
<context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_CSRF</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> </context-param> <context-param> <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name> <param-value>server</param-value> </context-param>

I don't know if I am misunderstanding something. Can somebody help me?

If you are concerned with security, please upgrade your PrimeFaces version. There are several developers on PF which undergo pen-tests with their applications and improvements are made constantly.

Yep if you upgrade to PrimeFaces 14.0.4 all of your issue above have been addressed.

If you can't upgrade take a look at this solution
